# Constructor Not Defined Queable Apex

Tags: apex, unit-test

Im trying to write a test method for a queable apex class.
It is telling me that Constructor not defined. I assume im doing something wrong or missing a step because I have both the list and the Id defined in my test class.

Would someone be able to tell me what i am missing or doing wrong please. This is my test class below.

```
@IsTest global class RAMAssistSetupTest {
@testSetup 
static void setup() {
    List<Fleet_Assist__c> RFA = new List<Fleet_Assist__c>();
    List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
    // add a parent account
    accounts.add(new Account(Name='Test Record'));
    // add 1 child Fleet Assist Record
    for (Integer i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        RFA.add(new Fleet_Assist__c(
            Opportunity_Name__c='Test Account'+i,Company__c='0017E000017Pu3Y',Contact__c= '0017E000017Pu3Y',Licenses__c=11
        ));
    }
    insert RFA;
    insert accounts;
}

static testmethod void testQueueable() {
    // query for test data to pass to queueable class
    Id accId = [select id from Account where name='Test Record'][0].Id;
    List<Fleet_Assist__c> RFA = [select id, name from Fleet_Assist__c where Company__r.Name like 'Test Account%'];
    // Create our Queueable instance
    RAMAssistSetup updater = new RAMAssistSetup(RFA, accId);
    // startTest/stopTest block to force async processes to run
    Test.startTest();        
    System.enqueueJob(updater);
    Test.stopTest();        
    // Validate the job ran. Check if record have correct accId now
    System.assertEquals(1, [select count() from Fleet_Assist__c where Company = :accId]);
}
```

}

This is my RAMAssistSetup

```
public class RAMAssistSetup {
@InvocableMethod(label='RAM Assist Setup ' description='This sets up ram assist')
public static void RAMAssistSetup(List<Id> FleetAssist) {
    List<Fleet_Assist__c> RFA =[Select Id from Fleet_Assist__c where id in :FleetAssist ];
    System.enqueueJob(new RestApiCall(FleetAssist));
}
public class RestApiCall implements System.Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {
    List<Id> RFA = new List<Id>() ; 
    public RestApiCall(List<Id> ids){
        RFA = ids ;
    }
    public void execute(System.QueueableContext ctx) {
        Fleet_Assist__c FA = [Select Id ,Contact_Email__c,Company__c,Contact_Full_Name__c,Company_Name_Text__c,Contact_Telephone__c,fm_Licenses__c,fm_Address__c from Fleet_Assist__c where id = :RFA limit 1] ;
        JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);    
        gen.writeStartObject();      
        gen.writeStringField('email',FA.Contact_Email__c);
        gen.writeStringField('sfId',FA.Company__c);
        gen.writeStringField('name',FA.Contact_Full_Name__c);
        gen.writeStringField('companyName',FA.Company_Name_Text__c);
        gen.writeStringField('tel',FA.Contact_Telephone__c);
        gen.writeStringField('address',FA.fm_Address__c);
        gen.writeStringField('licenses',FA.fm_Licenses__c);
        gen.writeEndObject();    
        String jsonS = gen.getAsString();
        System.debug('jsondebugs'+jsonS);

        // Sending the http body with JSON 

        String endpoint = '';
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json;charset=UTF-8');
        req.setbody(jsonS);
        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse response = http.send(req);
        // Parse the JSON response
        if (response.getStatusCode() != 200) {
            System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' +
                response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
        } else {
            System.debug(response.getBody());
        }

     }
}
```

}

Comment: What is the code for `RAMAssistSetup`? Does it contain a controller?

Comment: @DavidReed I have edited it and included it.

Answer (score 3):

You do not have a constructor in `RAMAssistSetup`. You're attempting to call one with a `List<Fleet_Assist__c>` and `Id` as parameters:

```
RAMAssistSetup updater = new RAMAssistSetup(RFA, accId);
```

Instead, you have a static method:

```
public static void RAMAssistSetup(List<Id> FleetAssist) {
```

which takes a `List<Id>`. Also, `RAMAssistSetup` is not your Queueable class; the inner class `RAMAssistSetup.RestApiCall` is.

To enqueue the Queueable, you'll have to call *its* constructor with a `List<Id`> as its parameter:

```
     RAMAssistSetup.RestApiCall updater = new RAMAssistSetup.RestApiCall(myListOfIds);
```

or call the static method and allow it to enqueue the job:

```
RAMAssistSetup.RAMAssistSetup(myListOfIds);
```

### Other Issues

There are a few other issues with this code and unit test class.

- You are doing test data setup, which is good. However, you're also hard-coding Salesforce Ids from outside the test context, which will not work. Your unit tests must create *all* of their required data.
- You have the deprecated `testmethod` keyword; use `@isTest` in all new code.
- You're using JSONGenerator syntax to build your outbound payload, which you probably don't need. It looks like you can just create an Apex wrapper class with the right member variables and directly serialize it.
- Your Queueable accepts a list of Ids, but only acts on the first one.